# Responsive design tab, ipad, iPhone, nexus7

Tags: css, css-float, media-queries

Already I am tried for responsive code different mobile ipad nexus7 and iPhone but my code is properly not working why? My hope was that I wouldn't need to create iPhone/iPad specific setups... but I am beginning to fear that I need to?
How to code individual mobile view  like iPad, nexus7, Iphone, tab etc

```
/* MOBILE PORTRAIT */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
     #panels-section {
         padding: 0;
     }
     .right-align {
         float: left;
         margin-top: 4px;
     }
     .privacy-right {
         padding: 20px 0 0;
         text-align: left;
     }
     .priv ul li a {
         float: left;
         text-decoration: none;
     }
     .mod {
         display: block;
         margin: 0px;
     }
 }

/* MOBILE LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .right-align {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .privacy-right {
        padding: 20px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .priv ul li a {
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .mod {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
    }
}

/* SMALL TABLET */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .right-align {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .privacy-right {
        padding: 20px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .priv ul li a {
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .mod {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
    }
 }

 /* TABLET/NETBOOK */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 

    /* COLUMN GRID */
    .g1,.g2,.g3 {display:inline; float: left}

    /* 2 COLUMN GRID */
    .g1 {width:48.0%}
    .g2 {width:48.0%}
    .g3 {width:98.0%}
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {}
```

Comment: As a mobile developer I **stongly** recommend using twitter bootstrap for mobile responsive design. Allowing my apps to adjust to all different sized screens is a VERY BIG plus and I can focus less on getting things to look right, and more at the inner working of the application.

Comment: also http://unsemantic.com/ may help - using these kind of tools saves a lot of headache

Comment: Unsemantic would be a really great choice for working on grids..